# How to get the setState reassigned in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, chart.js, use-state

I can't get the setState to update to the new value in the code below.

I'm trying to get it to create a dynamic line graph using chart.js. I'm getting the correct data from the dummy API but I can't get it to state to my useState.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import axios from "axios";

function Graph(){
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState([]);


  const chart = async () => {
    let empSal = [];
    let empAge = [];
    try {
      const res = await axios.get("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees");
      for (const dataObj of res.data.data) {
        empSal.push(parseInt(dataObj.employee_salary));
        empAge.push(parseInt(dataObj.employee_age));
      }
      setChartData({
        labels: empAge,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "level of thiccness",
            data: empSal,
            backgroundColor: ["rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)"],
            borderWidth: 4
          }
        ]
      });
      console.log(res.data)
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }    
   
    console.log(empSal, empAge);
    console.log(chartData)
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    chart();
  }, [chartData]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Data Vis</h1>
      <Line data={chartData}/>
    </div >
  );
};
export default Graph;
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow,
1 - The function should be moved into the useEffect. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1
2 - Not sure why chartData is on the dependency array, doesn't it get an infinite loop? If you want the function to run only 1 time, you can change [chartData] to [] https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1

Comment: So <Line /> component does not get rendered? You need to introduce loading state and wait component to render while you are fetching the data and setting the state

Comment: Is the issue that your code is render looping? The `useEffect` hook has a dependency on the `chartData` state and its callback calls `chart` which potentially calls `setChartData` and updates the `chartData` state. Don't update the state that is used as a dependency, or don't use a dependency that the hook updates. What are you trying to accomplish with this code? Can you walk us through the code, line-by-line, and explain what you expect it to do?

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome. and sure, so im essentially trying to call an api to grab data from a database in this case just some json data from a free api, and display it as a line chart with char.js. Im waiting for the response from the api to get two data sets and trying to store them into my useState using setChartData. they way im trying to store the data should be usuable with the <Line/> method from the chartjs library. but i cant get anything to set to my setState.

Answer (score 1):

- The function should be moved into the useEffect.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1

- Not sure why chartData is on the dependency array, doesn't it get an infinite loop? If you want the function to run only 1 time, you can change [chartData] to []

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

Comment: Thank you for the response Im calling the function within the useEffect but are you saying i need to declare it with in the useEffect? ive structured it like this before with sucess but im not sure why im getting back an empty object after setChartData is called

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the problem. The state was being updated correctly. I had the data formatted wrong within the data set so it wouldn't render anything on the page. I just had to remove the [] from around the background color line.